# How to compile Mach 3?

Tags: compilation, operating-system, mach, microkernel

I am interested in the [mach operating system](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/mach/public/www/mach.html) these days. However, I found it seems pretty difficult to build it on a modern Linux system, like Debian Wheezy.

So I wanna know if there is any way to build this and boot it?

Any ideas and advises are welcomed :-)

BTW: It seems that the Mach operating system is built by ODETools(odemake and something else). What is that? It pretty hard for me to find anything of this odetools.

Answer (score 0):

Try [GNU Mach building page](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/microkernel/mach/gnumach/building.html). It's microkernel which GNU Hurd is running on; I don't know if it's the same as you want to, but it can help anyway.